# Execute callback once every async tasks are finished in a forEach

Tags: node.js, postgresql, asynchronous

I'm writing some PostgreSQL transactions, and I need to execute a callback once every function in a forEach have been executed. Here is some code :

```
var sql = "BEGIN;UPDATE object SET name = "+data.name+", object_subtype_id = "+data.object_subtype_id+" WHERE id = "+data.id+";";
db.driver.execQuery(sql, function(err, result) {
  data.object_subtype.object_property_type.forEach(function(item) {
    db.driver.execQuery("WITH upsert AS (UPDATE object_property SET value = '"+item.value+"' WHERE object_property_type_id = "+item.id+" AND object_id = "+data.id+" RETURNING *) INSERT INTO object_property (object_property_type_id, object_id, value) SELECT "+item.id+", "+data.id+", '"+item.value+"' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM upsert);", function(err, nb) {
      // I need to send the COMMIT; here once all the functions in the forEach have been executed
    });
  });
});
```

I had look at [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) but I'm not sure how, or if I can, apply it to my situation.

Have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Combining async.series and async.each you'll end up with this beautiful snippet:

```
var sql = "BEGIN;UPDATE object SET name = "+data.name+", object_subtype_id = "+data.object_subtype_id+" WHERE id = "+data.id+";";

async.series([
  function (next) {
    db.driver.execQuery(sql, next);
  },
  function (next) {
    async.each(data.object_subtype.object_property_type, function (item, next) {
      db.driver.execQuery("WITH upsert AS (UPDATE object_property SET value = '"+item.value+"' WHERE object_property_type_id = "+item.id+" AND object_id = "+data.id+" RETURNING *) INSERT INTO object_property (object_property_type_id, object_id, value) SELECT "+item.id+", "+data.id+", '"+item.value+"' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM upsert);", next);
    }, next);
  }
], function (err, results) {
  // Not sure what you want to do with the result
});
```

It might need some tweaks depending on what you want to with the result.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use async (it sometimes complicates simple apps) JS way of doing is by reference counting. Do this;

```
var sql = "BEGIN;UPDATE object SET name = "+data.name+", object_subtype_id = "+data.object_subtype_id+" WHERE id = "+data.id+";";
db.driver.execQuery(sql, function(err, result) {
  var counter =0;
  data.object_subtype.object_property_type.forEach(function(item) {
    db.driver.execQuery("WITH upsert AS (UPDATE object_property SET value = '"+item.value+"' WHERE object_property_type_id = "+item.id+" AND object_id = "+data.id+" RETURNING *) INSERT INTO object_property (object_property_type_id, object_id, value) SELECT "+item.id+", "+data.id+", '"+item.value+"' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM upsert);", function(err, nb) {
      //THIS IS WHERE REFERENCE COUNTING HAPPENS
      counter++;
      if(counter === data.subtype.type.length) {
          COMMIT (since all callback functions returned
      }
      // I need to send the COMMIT; here once all the functions in the forEach have been executed
    });
  });
});
```